# Android Toolbar - NavigationUI.setupWithNavController in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I am trying to use the NavigationUI and toolbar's menu to navigate across fragments.

I follow the guide in Google as below:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui?hl=en#support_app_bar_variations

However, I cannot use the toolbar's menu to navigate from fragment A to fragment B

My Fragment has its own toolbar and menu as below XML

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:menu="@menu/menu" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

My toolbar menu is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:title="@string/fragmentA" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:title="@string/fragmentB" />
</menu>
```

The **NAV Host** is in my main activity with a nav graph as below:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    app:startDestination="@id/userList">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"/>
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"/>

</navigation>
```

In my fragment, I have below code to setup the NavigationUI navigation

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    }
```

Comment: So where do you call `setOnMenuItemClickListener`? `setupWithNavController` doesn't call that for you.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, So, it doesn't like bottom navigation view that the click event is handled by NavigationUI? I still need to setup my own event listener?

Comment: How do you inflate this menu in the fragment? Do you use `setHasOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: Thanks @Zain, I inflate my menu in XML. I didn't use **setHasOptionsMenu()**. My understanding is, **setHasOptionsMenu()** is for activity owed toolbar.

Comment: Did you solve this ?